# Change ONLY the bubble of information with a MKPinAnnotationView?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I want to use a normal MKPinAnnotationView, but I want to use a custom view for the callout. Every solution I can find seems to be a hack or doesn't maintain the normal dropped pin behavior

Can anyone provide an example of the simplest way to replace the callout of an MKPinAnnotationView?

Answer (score 1):

You have to override the

```
-(MKAnnotationView*) mapView:(MKMapView *)mkMapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
```

function, to return a custom MKAnnotationView. In this view (that you create), you can customise the layout using the drawRect function.

This is what my custom bubble looks like:

[image: Custom callout]

And this is my viewForAnnotation:

```
-(MKAnnotationView*) mapView:(MKMapView *)mkMapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
   if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[YourAnnotation class]]) {
      YourAnnotationView *yourAnnotationView = (YourAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"YourAnnotation"];

      if(!yourAnnotationView)
      {
         yourAnnotationView = [[YourAnnotationView alloc]
                               initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"YourAnnotation"];
      }
      [yourAnnotationView setTitle:annotation.title];
      [yourAnnotationView setSubtitle:annotation.subtitle];

      yourAnnotationView.draggable = YES;

      return yourAnnotationView;
   }
   else
   {
      MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                                            reuseIdentifier:@"GPXAnnotation"];
      annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;
      annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;

      annotationView.draggable = YES;
      return annotationView;
   }
   return nil;
}
```

Hope it can help you in the right direction!

Comment: Just so I understand, are you adding two annotations at the same coordinate? One is the pin annotation, and the other is the completely custom view to use?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but yes, you are right. I don't know if its possible to have it all in one annotation, I haven't looked into that since this is working for me. Let me know, if you need to see more code.